# WD 3TB external HD that is not recognized by Ubuntu 14.04 (the BIOS does support +2.2TB drives)

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I've got an Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, with a 4 TB hard drive.
My mother is an [Asus P8Z68-V/GEN3](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68VGEN3/), which natively supports hard drives larger than 2.2TB in 64-bit.

I've have two WD (western Digital) external USB 3.0 disks. One of 4TB and the other or 3TB. I can use the 4TB ithout any issue, but **when I add the 3TB, it says that "this location could not be displayed".** I've tried the 2.0 and 3.0 USB slot.

I do have a Windows 7 machine that does recognize it.

What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was solved after I accessed the drive from a Windows computer. Just that.

I've inserted it again on my linux machine and it works normally, as it should.

Just in case it helps someone, some day.

Comment: No, not "just that"... Your drive had logical error that, with NTFS, can only be corrected in Windows and they were, automatically.